# A QWERTY-based keyboard puzzle

Tags: word, cipher

There is a puzzle and clue. Answer is one (real) word only.

Riddle: dtqrgvl

Clue is: qwerty based keyboard

Comment: **Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!** To be sure, this is your own puzzle, right? Otherwise you have to give attribution. You haven't done anything wrong; this is just a routine check.

Comment: Hi there. This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere - please could you edit your post to note where you found it? This site policy enables original content creators to be credited. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t want to be annoying but if I have got the right answer can you please give it the green tick underneath the upvotes button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> **MEADOWS**

> The answer is obtained by superimposing the alphabet over the QWERTY key board layout order so A=Q, B=W, C=E D=R and then converting from the letter string to the answer by treating its letters as part of the QWERTY order and then find its counterpart in the Alphabetical order. So D=M, T=E, Q=A and so on.